# Firebase setValue Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Having an error when using setValue when updating firebase database. Im not sure what the issue is.

Error log output.

[image]

```
 val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
 val ref = database.getReference("users").child(firebaseUser.uid)
 val map = HashMap<String, Any>()

                            map.put("username", username.toLowerCase())
                            map.put("email", email)
                            map.put("rank", 0)
                            map.put("message_count", 0)
                            map.put("date_joined", "N/A")
                            map.put("purchase", false)
                            map.put("initial_payment_option", "N/A")
                            map.put("current_payment_option", "N/A")
                            map.put("subscription", "N/A")
                            map.put("family_discount", "N/A")
                            ref.setValue(map)
```

Gradle App Module:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```

Comment: Please don't use images for code and error messages.  It's much better if you simply copy and paste the message into your question, which makes it easier to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Are you using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'`?